# How to put values of one hash map in to another when both types are different

Tags: java, hashmap

MAP 1 :-

```
Map<String, List<Long>> prjReleaseMap = (Map<String, List<Long>>) configMap.get(PROJECTRELEASEMAP);
```

MAP 2 : -

```
Map<Long, List<Long>> newprjReleaseMap = new HashMap<>();
```

I want to put map 1 value in map 2 ..

Comment: what about the key(String) you want to convert it to Long or what exactly mean?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that keys in map1 will always be strings representing long values? Or can there be keys like "abc" (in that case what do you want to do with them)?

Comment: yeah i want to convert it in long and the i want to put it in newprjReleaseMap

Comment: i want to do something like this newprjReleaseMap.putAll(prjReleaseMap) but it is showing casting error - The method putAll(Map<? extends Long,? extends List<Long>>) in the type Map<Long,List<Long>> is not applicable for the arguments (Map<String,List<Long>>)

Comment: But is it ***guaranteed*** that every key in map1 will be string which can be safely converted to Long? Compiler can't assume such thing so it prevents your code from compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop on the key set then covert the key and put it on the new `Map`. However, you need to be sure all the key `Strings` are actually to `Long` else you will get an exception.

```
    prjReleaseMap.keySet().forEach(e -> {
        newprjReleaseMap.put(Long.parseLong(e), prjReleaseMap.get(e));
    });
```

**Edit**:
You can convert the `List<Interger>` to `List<Long>` before putting the value to the new map. Please refer to the below code.

```
    prjReleaseMap.keySet().forEach(e -> {
        newprjReleaseMap.put(Long.parseLong(e),
                prjReleaseMap.get(e).stream().map(i -> i.longValue()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    });
```

As mentioned in the comment you can directly iterate over the map instead of iterating over the key set.

```
    prjReleaseMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
        newprjReleaseMap.put(Long.parseLong(k), v.stream().map(i -> i.longValue()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    });
```

Comment: Hi amit ! it worked for me. thanks .

Comment: Great!!! Happy to help you.

Comment: Amit Bera one more concern .. if i want to caste value also from integer to long . then what to do ?

Comment: like Map<String, List<Integer>> prjReleaseMap = (Map<String, List<Integer>>) configMap.get(PROJECTRELEASEMAP); to Map<Long, List<Long>> newprjReleaseMap = new HashMap<>();

Comment: @annu I have edited my answer. I believe that will solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah its working . thanks a ton :-)

Comment: iterating over the `keySet()` and doing a lookup in the map for each key is sub-optimal. it would be better to use `prjReleaseMap.keySet().forEach(...)` or much better `prjReleaseMap.forEach(...)`.

Comment: example --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51347097/how-to-put-values-of-one-hash-map-in-to-another-when-both-types-are-different/51348796#51348796

Comment: @Aominè You are right. I have added the solution in my answer using `prjReleaseMap.forEach`. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8 you can use :

```
Map<Long, List<Long>> newprjReleaseMap = prjReleaseMap.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> Long.parseLong(k.getKey()), Map.Entry::getValue));
```

I assume that all the keys can be converted to Long.

---

If you want to take only the entries where the key is valid you can use filter like so :

```
Map<Long, List<Long>> newprjReleaseMap = prjReleaseMap.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(k -> checkKey(k.getKey()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> Long.parseLong(k.getKey()), Map.Entry::getValue));

...

public static boolean checkKey(String value) {
    try {
        Long.parseLong(value);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can do it without the overhead of stream :). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51347097/how-to-put-values-of-one-hash-map-in-to-another-when-both-types-are-different/51348796#51348796

Answer (score 1):

if all you want to do is construct a new `Map<Long, List<Long>>` where the `prjReleaseMap` keys are converting to a `long` value as well as keeping the values as they were then it can be done as follows:

```
prjReleaseMap.forEach((k, v) -> newprjReleaseMap.put(Long.parseLong(k), v));
```

However, if `newprjReleaseMap` could potentially have some entries already in it and you want to merge the entries of `prjReleaseMap` into `newprjReleaseMap` then you can do it with the `merge` method:

```
prjReleaseMap.forEach((k, v) -> newprjReleaseMap.merge(Long.parseLong(k), v, (o, n) -> o));
```

This assumes the keys of `prjReleaseMap` are `long` values represented as a `String`.  The `(o, n) -> o` function above is known as the remapping function, in the case of a key collision, it's called to decide whether to keep the old value (`o`)  or new value (`n`) or to call another custom function generating a completely new value.